# Script to check the data inside the file

Tags: unix

I have a requirement and any pointers on simple script to do this?

I have couple of files in a folder and my target is to move them to a different folder
Before moving to new folder, i have to check each file with below condition and only move the file if the condition met

Condition: On each file, go to last line and check the string position from 59 to 75 and see if value is zero or non zero. if it is non zero then only i have to move the file

Condition: On each file, go to last line and check the string position from 59 to 75 and see if value is zero or non zero. if it is non zero then only i have to move the file

Comment: What kind of script? How do you check if chars in those range are 0? Do all of them have to be 0 or are they surrounded with spaces? Do you have to check all files in folder or is there some condition to be met so that file is processed? Give us some material to work with.

Comment: Welcome, but you're expected to show us the code you've written that doesn't work. Stackoverflow exists to help people fix their code. We're not going to do your homework for you. One solution is to use a program such as `sed` or `awk` which can examine whether specific characters in the last line of a file are all `0`'s.

Comment: I have to check on each file in the folder and each file contains many lines but the condition is to check on the last line. I am using tail to get the last line in one string and using substring. When I used tail the last line was not writing in to the string causing me stopper. In the example below, sample_data is the file name where I have the data. I am trying to put the last line from the file into the string 'last_line' but data not wringing into the string but tail command is working.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
tail -l sample_data>>last_line
echo 'last line:-' $last_line

string3='P800000000000003620000000000000600000000000000001379517939000000000002117636'
final_string=${string3:59-18}
echo 'final string:-'  $final_string



Output:
last line:-
final string:- 00000001379517939000000000002117636

Comment: Don't put your solution in a comment. Edit your original question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -l sample_data>>last_line
```

That statement appends the last line from *sample_data* to the file *last_line*. It does not put that line in a shell variable named `last_line`. Which is why the next statement does not echo the last line. Also, you wrote `tail -l` (that's an "ell" character, not `1`) which isn't valid. Always copy/paste rather than retyping the code.

```
echo 'last line:-' $last_line
string3='P800000000000003620000000000000600000000000000001379517939000000000002117636'
final_string=${string3:59-18}
```

Your substring syntax is wrong. The two values should be separated by a colon. Which is why the next statement doesn't output the expected substring. Because Bash treats the offset and length values as arithmetic expressions your `59-18` is treated as an offset of 41 with a length extending to the end of the string.

```
echo 'final string:-' $final_string
```

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
last_line=$(tail -1 sample_data)
final_string=${last_line:59:75-59}
echo 'last line: ' $last_line
echo 'final string: ' $final_string
```

It is unclear whether the offsets in your question (`59` and `75`) are zero or one based, and in the case of `75` inclusive or exclusive of that position. So you may need to modify the substring slicing in the second statement of my solution. Still, it should be obvious how to modify my solution if my assumptions regarding those values are incorrect.